# SQL Server named instance in Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, sql-server-2019

How can I run a named SQL Server instance inside a Docker container?

I have an application that has a connection string pointing to a named SQL Server instance, something like `Data Source=HostName\InstanceName`; this connection string is very problematic for me to change. I want to dockerize that SQL Server instance. I already configured it so that I can connect to the dockerized instance via `sqlcmd` using `sqlcmd -S HostName` but when using `sqlcmd -S HostName\InstanceName` (which should be equivalent to the connection string this application is using) it does not establish a connection.

Comment: SQL Server on Linux doesn't support Named Instances.

Comment: Why not remove the instance name from your connection string? If you must keep the name for some reason, add a port number (Data Source=HostName\InstanceName,1433) so that the instance name is ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker containers do not support named instances; this is mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/515):

> There is no concept of a named instance. Every container can have a unique name. 
> ...
> Containers don't have a concept of running multiple SQL Server instances. So there is no option of running more than one instance name.

Really, you should change the connection string. An alternative if you can't change the connection string (but you really should change the connection string) is to create an alias on each client using their local client network utility or configuration manager.

For example, you can create an alias on the client that points to `HostName\InstanceName` but, underneath, the mapping would actually redirect to `HostName,2700` (assuming `2700` is the port you specified in `docker run ... -p 2700:1433 ...`).

Aliases are talked about more thoroughly [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1620/how-to-setup-and-use-a-sql-server-alias/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and I talk about using custom and specific ports for Docker containers [here](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/14/quick-tip-multiple-docker-containers).

Did I mention it is much more logical to change your connection strings? *That* is probably the problem you want to fix.

Comment: For posterity, if you want to connect from SSMS, (a) Server Name: IP Address Only; (b) Authentication: SQL Server Authentication; (c) Login: sa . Thanks