# SQL Server Docker: how to connect?

Tags: sql-server, docker

I have Windows10, installed SQL Server sql2019, i.e. my-machine\sql2019.
Also, I have run a SQL Server 2019 Docker on the same machine as described in the MS doc:

```
>docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

The questions are:

1. How to run Docker with named SQL Server instance ?
2. How to connect to the SQL server in Docker?

Comment: *"How to run Docker with named SQL Server instance?"* You can't. Named instances are *only* supported on Windows.

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: Have you read the documentation [Deploy and **connect to** SQL Server Docker containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-deployment?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-powershell)?

Comment: @Larnu : ok, but I have  Windows 10 OS + windows based docker

Comment: Windows based Docker Containers are no longer supported, @ZedZip . [Update- Beta program for SQL Server on Windows container is suspended.](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/update-beta-program-for-sql-server-on-windows-container-is/ba-p/2516639)

Comment: @larnu ok, in any case: how can I connect SSMS to the SQL Server in Docker?

Comment: Just like you normally would. Put the host name in (I assume `localhost`) and if needed the port that you have mapped the service running within docker to on the container's host.

Comment: ok, it is the same machine: SQL Server 2019 installed and Docker+SQL Server 2019 run.

Comment: @ZedZip. `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest` is a Linux docker image. Rather than named instance, just expose a different port for each container (e.g. `-p 12345:1433`).

Comment: I do: PS H:\_Docker> docker run --network=bridge --name sql19 -h sql19 -it --rm -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=sql19pwd" -
p 10433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest and then in SSMS on the same machine: localhost:10433, sa, sql19pwd - cannot connect.

Comment: Use a comma instead of colon to separate the host and port: `localhost,10433`

Comment: @DanGuzman : I try "localhost, 10433" and "127.0.0.1,10433" - SSMS cannot find the docker SQL Server. May be need to run the docker with any additional parameters?

Comment: And if you really made your password `sql19pwd` I would check that the container is still running (`docker ps`) and if not you should see why using `docker logs sql19`. You need a more complex password or SQL Server won't run.

Comment: @AaronBertrand you are right about password!!!!! Please write your comment as an answer I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you can't have a named instance. If you need multiple containers, you can just use different ports. This was addressed in another question here:

   - [SQL Server named instance in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69973970/61305)

     ...and I talked about it here when I first started playing:
   - [VS Code on Mac Meets SQL Server on Linux (in Docker)](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/vs-code-mac-sql-linux-docker)
2. Your password `sql19pwd` is too weak. SQL Server will try to start, and then shut down. You can confirm this using `docker logs <container name>`. This was also addressed in a roundabout way here:

   - [SQL Server on Mac with Docker : Login failed for user 'password too short'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70022621/61305)

In your case:

```
docker logs sql19
```

Will yield, somewhere toward the end:

> ERROR: Unable to set system administrator password: Password validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is not complex enough. The password must be at least 8 characters long and contain characters from three of the following four sets: Uppercase letters, Lowercase letters, Base 10 digits, and Symbols..

If you try a more complex but shorter password, it would be:

> ERROR: Unable to set system administrator password: Password validation failed. The password does not meet SQL Server password policy requirements because it is too short. The password must be at least 8 characters..

I've been using mnemonics for Docker container passwords, but also trying to avoid characters like `#` and `$` which can have special meaning. My favorite recently when using Azure SQL Edge is `3dg3Y0urB3ts`.